# Changing app language from code doesn't work in iOS

Tags: ios, swift3

I try to switch app language from code in my iOS app. I do this

```
    var lang = "en"        
    print("lang 1 = \(lang)")
    print("lang 2 = \(UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "AppleLanguages")![0])")

    UserDefaults.standard.setValue([lang], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    print("lang 3 = \(UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "AppleLanguages")![0])")
```

And the code above prints this.

```
lang 1 = en
lang 2 = es
lang 3 = es
```

Why 'lang' is not saved to UserDefaults? What I have missed?

Comment: is this code from a playground?

Comment: @dirtydanee, nope, this is from a ViewController of my project

Comment: What device do you use for testing (model, version) ?

Comment: what happens and what you want to do ?

Comment: I've tried on emulator on different models and the result is the same

Comment: I just want to change app language but what I want is not saved to UserDefaults

Comment: I tried your code on a real device and it works fine for me. Are you able to launch it on a real device?

Comment: Yes. I'v just now launch my app on real iPhone 6. It turned out that value for language is changed after I restart application

Comment: looking at your code, it should be working just fine. The problem should be somewhere else, not in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I had a identical problem, most likely it's a case in the configuration of the run `scheme`, if in `application language` is non set `system language` the parameter will be forced.[image]
in this case you will **not** be able to overwrite `AppleLanguages`